# Why is MapNotify sent too early in xlib

Tags: c, x11, xlib, xorg

I am using xlib for the first time in C, not C++. I want to draw a test box to the screen but I have to wait for xorg to create the window. I have a callback for MapNotify which is called to early. I added a 3 second delay and after the 3 seconds the box draws fine. This solution is obviously just for testing however I cannot get the callback to work properly.

Code (notice my delay is commented, when commenting the function stops working)

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define white 0xFFFFFF
#define black 0

#define red 0xFF0000
#define green 0xFF00
#define blue 0xFF

void delay(unsigned int millis) {
    clock_t start = clock();
    while(clock() < start + millis);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL); // Get default display
    if(dpy == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, XDefaultRootWindow(dpy), 0, 0, 800, 800, 0, 0, black); // Make a """simple""" window

    XMapWindow(dpy, win);
    XSelectInput(dpy, win, StructureNotifyMask); // Get MapNotify events

    GC gc = XCreateGC(dpy, win, 0, 0);
    if(gc == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make a GC\n");
        return 1;
    }

    XSetBackground(dpy, gc, white);
    XSetForeground(dpy, gc, white);
    XSync(dpy, true);

    while(true) { // Await for screen, TODO this is called too early for some reason
        XEvent e;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &e);
        printf("Got event: %d\n", e.type);
        if(e.type == MapNotify)
            break;
    }
    //delay(3000);

    XFillRectangle(dpy, win, gc, 5, 5, 100, 100);
    XFlush(dpy);

    while(true) { // Await for window close, this doesn't actually work but I don't care for now
        XEvent e;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &e);
        if(e.type == UnmapNotify)
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _called too early_? Do you mean, that you don't see the results of your rendering? Well, draw on an expose event (note the count argument). See also:: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/exposure

Comment: To wait for specific events, one would typically use: [XIfEvent](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/manipulating-event-queue/XIfEvent.html)

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Yes, the test square is not rendered without the sleep. From what I understand when reading the docs (this is my first xlib project) this event will trigger when the window is in view. If the user has focus stealing prevention or is using a tiling window manager the event will not be called fast enough.

Comment: Honestly, i do not understand what you mean by _'called fast enough'_ (map or expose events?). Could you please direct me to the documenation where you've got the idea from?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your follow-up comment above, i think the following statement (from [XMapWindow](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XMapWindow.html)) does answer it best:

> If the window is an InputOutput window, XMapWindow() generates Expose events on each InputOutput window that it causes to be displayed.
>
> If the client maps and paints the window and if the client begins processing events, the window is painted twice. To avoid this, **first ask for Expose events and then map the window**, so the client processes input events as usual.
>
> The event list will include Expose for each window that has appeared on the screen. **The client's normal response to an Expose event should be to repaint the window.** This method usually leads to simpler programs and to proper interaction with window managers.

To say it differently: A map event is not an indicator that a window is displayed on the screen, but rather that the client has been assigned to its ancestor's hierarchy and is ready to be displayed.

When it is time to be displayed, then an expose event will be the indicator for that.

---

A minimal example (without error handling):

```
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main()
{
    Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(
        dpy,
        XDefaultRootWindow(dpy),
        0, 0,
        800, 800,
        0, 0, 0
    );
    XSelectInput(dpy, win, KeyPressMask | ExposureMask);
    XMapWindow(dpy, win);

    GC gc = XCreateGC(dpy, win, 0, 0);
    XSetBackground(dpy, gc, 0);
    XSetForeground(dpy, gc, 0xffffffff);

    int active = 1;
    XEvent evt;

    while (active) {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &evt);
        switch (evt.type) {
            case KeyPress:
                active = 0;
            break;
            case Expose:
                XFillRectangle(
                    dpy,
                    win,
                    gc,
                    evt.xexpose.x+10, evt.xexpose.y+10,
                    evt.xexpose.width-20, evt.xexpose.height-20
                );
            break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(dpy, win);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
}
```

If you compile and run the code, you should see a window that is filled with a white rectangle (based on the expose rect).

Comment: I changed the event to Expose and the mask to ExposureMask but nothing is drawn still

Comment: I've posted an example code that runs fine on _my_ machine. What happens if you try it on _your_ machine?

Comment: It works for me too, why is my code not working then?

Comment: I took your code (1:1) and replaced `StructureNotifyMask` with `ExposureMask` and `MapNotify` with `Expose`. Anything else unchanged, worked for me, no issues at all. So, i don't know what else the cause might be (besides the fact, that redrawing on expose events is the proper thing to do).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what command did you use to compile? I am using `gcc -o hello hello.c -lX11` are you linking something else or something like that?

Comment: `gcc -Wall -o main main.c -lX11`, i always turn warnings on and yes, the filename differs.Arch linux, rolling release, pure X (no wayland), Gnome, Nvidia blob.